# How do i loop and find the hausdorff distance for each pair?

Tags: python

given that

```
u = np.array([(1.0, 0.0),
              (0.0, 1.0),
              (-1.0, 0.0),
              (0.0, -1.0)])
v = np.array([(2.0, 0.0),
              (0.0, 2.0),
              (-2.0, 0.0),
              (0.0, -4.0)])
```

How do i find the hausdorff distance for each pair to obtain the result. For example

```
directed_hausdorff(u[i], v[i])[0]  #where i is the array point
```

1. 1
2. 1
3. 1
4. 3

For starter, I had tried without loop

```
HD = directed_hausdorff(u[0],v[0])
print(HD)

--> which should be giving me a result of 1 as i'm taking the 1st array in u & v
--> however i am getting the error 'tuple index out of range'
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: For each point in u, find the distance to the closet point in v.  Take the maximum of those distances.  You need to write your own code.

Comment: @BWallDev i had tried looping it into indices and finding the hausdorff distance based on the indices but it is just not working

Comment: @FrankYellin I do not quite understand what you are saying. i am trying to find for all the pair and not just 1 max distance. meaning i am trying to find the hausdorff distance based on pair u(1.0, 0.0) & v(2.0, 0.0), u(0.0, 1.0) & v(0.0, 2.0) so forth.

Comment: it would be a good idea to edit your post and include your code so we can see where you might be going wrong.

Comment: I was just quoting the definition of the Hausdorff distance.  For each u, find the distance to each of the v's and take the minimum.  Now take the maximum of those minimums.

Comment: @FrankYellin I understand the definition of the Hausdorff distance. It only gives me the max distance between the 2 array. However, i am trying to find the distance for each pair instead.

Comment: Is the question how to find the difference between two points?  The distance between <x1, y1> and <x2, y2> is sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2).  Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import directed_hausdorff

u = np.array([(1.0, 0.0),
              (0.0, 1.0),
              (-1.0, 0.0),
              (0.0, -1.0)])
v = np.array([(2.0, 0.0),
              (0.0, 2.0),
              (-2.0, 0.0),
              (0.0, -4.0)])
for i in u:
  for j in v:
    print(directed_hausdorff(np.array([i]),np.array([j])))
  print('\n')
```

EDIT......
For same indices

```
for i,j in zip(u,v):
  print(directed_hausdorff(np.array([i]),np.array([j])))
```

Comment: Yes! this is what i am looking for. Is there any ways to obtain just the distance pair for u(1.0, 0.0) & v(2.0, 0.0), ... , u(0.0, -1.0) & v(0.0, 4.0)? As the above code iterates u[0] against all of v

Comment: If you find this useful then please upvote and accept the answer. :)

Comment: It runs for all points in u and v. check the number of print statements ( its 4*4 = 16)

Comment: Yes. the answer is useful. But is there any ways that it only runs for the points that is in the same array index? such as u[0] against v[0], u[1] against v[1]? As i do not require the distance for u[0] against v[1] and so forth

Comment: quick question, how do i actually store the result? i tried append, however only the last value is recorded.

Comment: This is my code
a = []
for i,j in zip(u,v):
    HD = directed_hausdorff(np.array([i]),np.array([j]))[0]
    print('Hausdorff Distance at point = ', HD)
    a.append(HD)
print(HD)